# How to populate a 2D numpy array with randomly generated1D elements without repeats

Tags: arrays, numpy

I am trying to initiate a physical Monte Carlo simulation by creating a 2D numpy array, populated with N 1D elements that correspond to x, y, and z positions of each particle. However, the array must be populated without any two particles overlapping.

I am currently attempting to create a list, fill it with 3 random integers, then check in the list is in the array; and if it is, loop back to the point of creating the list of random numbers and try again. Adding the list to the array if it does not already exist in the array.

```
N = 10 #number of particles
L = 10 #length of box side
particle_positions = np.zeros([N,3], dtype=int)
i = 0
for particle in particle_positions:
    z = True
    while z == True:
        r = [rnd.randint(0,L),rnd.randint(0,L),rnd.randint(0,L)]
        if np.equal(particle_positions[:(i+1)],r).any() == True:
            z = True
            continue
        else:
            particle_positions[i] = r
            z = False
            i += 1
```

Yet, no matter how I attempt this I run into stange complications (that is, I'm doing something wrong and I dont know what) whereupon the code skips elements that are unique without adding them to the array.

Fairly new to python, and coding in general, so I suspect I'm probably making some mistake obvious to you veterans out there - if indeed I'm not overcomplicating the entire process anyway.

Appreciate any help massively.

Comment: `np.equal(particle_positions[:(i+1)],r).any()` I don't think this is doing what you want. You want to know if all of a row is equal?

Comment: Yes, you're correct in what i was trying to attempt. And my suspicion is that np.equal(etc.) was not behaving as I suspected; although it was working in a previous iteration of what I'm attempting...just probably by accident.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following, using [`permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations):

```
from itertools import permutations
import numpy as np

# random number generator
r = np.random.default_rng()

N = 10  # number of particles
L = 10  # length of box size

# get all permutations of 3 L values
A = np.array([p for p in permutations(range(L), 3)])

# draw N random values (without replacement)
unique = A[r.choice(A.shape[0], N, replace=False), :]
```

Comment: That seems like a much more elegant solution, thank you!

Comment: Thanks. If a solution is useful please consider upvoting it and/or marking it as accepted.

Comment: I realise now that np.array([p for p in itt.combinations_with_replacement(range(L), 3)]) is actually the function I needed; otherwise values such as (9,9,9), (0,0,0) are excluded.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to check if the paricle already exists in the list.

```
numpy.any([ numpy.all( numpy.equal(o, r) ) for o in particle_positions[:i]])
```

Your check seems to see if any single value lines up.